# How to check whether a shell process has job-control enabled?

Tags: shell, process, job-control

Is there a way to programmatically check whether a given (shell) process has job-control enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by `job-control enabled`? Do you want to know if a given shell has jobs in background/foreground?

Comment: In Bash, at least, the `set` builtin can enable job-control (`set -m`) or disable it (`set +m`). If job-control is disabled, attempting to suspend a foreground process (e.g. by typing Ctrl-Z in Vim) won't work, and I'm looking for a way to check whether that's the case before attempting to suspend.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a file (possibly in `/proc/pid_of_your_shell/...`) which has the shell options whose are set, I don't think so. However you can use `ioctl` to *read* the stdin from a **tty** (or for example `/dev/pts/2` which may be your current shell). using that you can run the command necessary for knowing if job-control is enabled. Nevertheless the script should be run as root.

Comment: I tried using a `ioctl` and worked perfectly, however maybe you *don't want to/cannot* use `ioctl` or run the program as root.

Comment: Yeah, at this point I'm realizing I asked the question more out of curiosity than necessity.

Comment: It should be possible to use `ioctl` to run that command but the problem is that your `/dev/pts/somenumber` should be running a shell sesion, If it's running another program such as vim I think it would be trickier to run the command with `ioctl`. I'll try to give a read to `ioctl` to know If it's possible to catch the stdin  by pid instead of tty.